# How to achieve similar Content Swipe effect / transition as found on lapierrequitourne.com

Tags: jquery, wordpress, transition

just wondering if anyone could help point me in the right direction in trying to achieve a content swipe out/in effect as seen on http://www.lapierrequitourne.com/

Seems like some kind of js based page transition to me, but not sure.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://builtwith.com/lapierrequitourne.com

Comment: thanks for the link, thats a useful site. Good jumping of point for some further research.